# Rails : find all associated entries habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Document`and a model `KeyWord`.

The table keywords has a lot more entries than keywords are associated to documents.

I need to select only those keywords that are actually attributed to Document.

I've tried:

```
Document.keywords.map { |e| e.keywrd }
```

and this :

```
Document.keywords.select(:keywrd)
```

That returns this error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `keywords' for #<Class:0x007fcd100d2b38>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just do

```
Keyword.joins(:documents)
```

Which should get you all keywords which have documents because it'll do an inner join

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the specific `Document` first.

```
document = Document.find(1)
document.keywords
```

The keywords all belong to an instance of the `Document` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your exemple you are using static methods that do not require an instantiated object. you should use an Instance methode (called from an object as **[Hassanin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702436/hassanin-ahmed)** suggested in his answer)

And make sure that you declared the association between Document and Keyword.